# Updating Data from Access Database from Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have a simple tool built using excel vba to update existing records and also to add new records to an access database. The goal is to use only 2 clicks to complete the action.

First Part - Resolved (Retrieve Data from Access Database): I have created a excel table that queries data from access database in a tab named "Mapping Matrix" , so everytime an update is required, will use a function to refresh the data.

So, I will update the existing data in the Sheet "Mapping Matrix", or even add new data before I will require this data to be propagated into my access database.

Second Part - ***Please help*** (Update the access database "Mapping" using the excel spreadsheet tab "Mapping Matrix")

Here is what I have done to try update existing records with that queried in Excel. However I am faced with this error message that says "The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'F1'. Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again."

Do not quite understand how to fix the error, as I have not applied F1 in the code.

Note: I will require this data to replace that in the access database (not adding on to existing data)

Thanks all in advance!

```
Public Sub Populate_Data()


  Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  dbPath = "Access Database Path.mdb"
  dbWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  dbWs = Application.ActiveSheet.Name
  scn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
  dsh = "[" & Application.ActiveSheet.Name & "$]"
  cn.Open scn

  ssql = "INSERT INTO Mapping ([Field1], [Field2], [Field3]) "
  ssql = ssql & "SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & dsh


  cn.Execute ssql

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: Thanks Nahuel for advising. I have amended my question.. my apologies for not presenting in the correct manner